# Image to ASCII art using custom running text

Tags: p5.js, ascii-art

How do I generate ASCII art from an image using custom text (poetry, quotes etc) which run across the screen and form the image ? I am referring to the example mentioned here at 10:58 in this [video](https://youtu.be/55iwMYv8tGI). Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucky for you, The Coding Train is absolutely amazing. All of their projects and examples are on [thecodingtrain.com](https://thecodingtrain.com/). More specifically the example you are referring to is [here](https://editor.p5js.org/codingtrain/sketches/LNBpdYQHP).

Let me know if you have any questions, I'll be happy to help.